# DisplayProperties empty when creating a MediaPlaybackItem from file

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, media-player, windows-10-universal

I'm creating a playlist from files using the default `MediaPlaybackItem` constructor:

```
songs = a.OfType<StorageFile>().Select(o => new MediaPlaybackItem(MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(o))).ToList();
```

But for some reason this process doesn't preserve the file properties, which are rather important in case of a music playback software.

For reference:

```
// This works just fine
var prop = await (_a as StorageFile).Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
// This doesn't.
var item = new MediaPlaybackItem(MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile((StorageFile)_a));
item.GetDisplayProperties().MusicProperties;
```

The `DisplayProperties` of an item, as well as `MusicProperties` attached to it are empty.

Is there any way to take care of that ***during*** the item creation or do I have to asynchronously assign properties after creating the item one by one?

```
foreach(var _a in a)
{
    var prop = await (_a as StorageFile).Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
    var item = new MediaPlaybackItem(MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile((StorageFile)_a));
    var attached = item.GetDisplayProperties().MusicProperties;
    attached.AlbumArtist = prop.AlbumArtist;
    attached.AlbumTitle = prop.Album;
    // ...
    songs.Add(item);
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, we can only programmatically provide metadata for media items by calling [GetDisplayProperties()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplaybackitem#Windows_Media_Playback_MediaPlaybackItem_GetDisplayProperties), setting the data of the returned [MediaItemDisplayProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/mediaitemdisplayproperties), and then calling [ApplyDisplayProperties(MediaItemDisplayProperties)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplaybackitem#Windows_Media_Playback_MediaPlaybackItem_ApplyDisplayProperties_Windows_Media_Playback_MediaItemDisplayProperties_) like what you've done.

But there is a new **prerelease** property named [AutoLoadedDisplayProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplaybackitem#Windows_Media_Playback_MediaPlaybackItem_AutoLoadedDisplayProperties) in [MediaPlaybackItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplaybackitem). With setting this property, the system should automatically load metadata from the content to display in the System Media Transport Controls. However, please note ***Some information relates to pre-released product which may be substantially modified before it’s commercially released. Microsoft makes no warranties, express or implied, with respect to the information provided here.***

You are welcome to join [Windows Insider](https://insider.windows.com/) and try the latest Insider Preview SDK.